# ¿Como puedo enviar una tabla bootstrap por email en php sin perder formato?

Tags: php

estoy intentando generar un reporte, recupero mis datos de la base de datos y formo una tabla con ello, quiero darle salida por medio de un mail en php

```
mail($to,"Reportex","",$headers);
```

el problema es el formato bootstrap se pierde.

aqui el codigo:

```
$correos ="Bcc: mail@here.com\r\n";
    $headers = "From: remitente>\r\n";
    $headers .= $correos;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $boundary = uniqid("HTMLEMAIL");
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;".
                "boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.\r\n\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "--$boundary\r\n".
                "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n".
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
    $headers .= chunk_split(base64_encode(strip_tags($content)));
    $headers .= "--$boundary\r\n".
                "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n".
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
    $headers .= chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    mail($correos,"Reporte Seguimiento Productividad: ".$fecha1,"",$headers);
```

Comment: Muestra el código con lo que haz intentado para poder entender lo que haz hecho y corregirte

Comment: Lo dejare hechale un vistazo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.-** En la cabecera del correo, tu variable `headers`, agregaste el atributo `Content-Type`?

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

**2.-** Como estas referenciando `bootstrap` en el codigo de tu mail? Desde un recurso publico al que se puede acceder desde cualquier lugar:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

O solo pones la ruta relativa de tu servidor

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Esto puede afectar pues el archivo sera descargado para visualizar el mail en el equipo de quien abre el correo, si no esta el recurso de manera publica no lo encontrara y no mostrara el estilo que deseas.

Comment: Gracias, efectivo